# How does the Autofill Chrome extension work? And can I implement something similar in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-chrome-extension, autofill

I am wondering how the Autofill Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk) autofills form data as a page is loading in text input fields without even changing the input field's values (as far as I can see). When I look in browser developer tools in Chrome, there is no trace of the extension changing any of the input elements' values because the input elements don't have value attributes.

Also, is there any way I can implement something similar to this in an iOS app I'm building? I wouldn't know where to start. The only way to autofill I can imagine is scraping webpages as they load, looking for identifiers of input fields, then changing the value attributes of the input fields. But, obviously, there are some forms I encounter without value attributes!

Answer (score 0):

Yes
in ios 12, We can implement autofill extension which will prompt emailId password, Once saved
Please check below link:
[Apple AutoFill Extension Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/721/#:%7E:text=In%20iOS%2012%2C%20there%20is,saved%20in%20the%20password%20manager.)